# What is homogeneity? How do we use it?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In Haim Brezis's book "Functional Analysis," the page $35$ writes the corollary $2.7$:

> Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces and let $T$ be a continuous
>   linear operator from $E$ to $F$, that is **bijective**, i.e. injective
>   (= one-to-one) and surjective. Then $T^{-1}$ is also continuous (from
>   $F$ into $E$).

The proof goes like this and I will parapharse it a little bit to make it simpler.

Proof. By Open Mapping Theorem and injectivity of $T$, it implies whenever $x \in E$ with $\|Tx\| <c,$ we will have $\|x\| < 1.$ By homogeneity, we find that

$$\|x\| \leq \frac{1}{c} \|Tx\| \quad \forall x \in E$$

and therefore $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

Here is my doubt: why we can use homogeneity here? What does it really mean? How we use homogeneity in other cases? (group theory, ring theory, or category theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He simply means $\forall \lambda\; \lambda Tx=T(\lambda x)$. Since if you know $$\Vert Tx \Vert \leq c \implies \Vert x \Vert \leq 1$$ 
(I use weak inequalities, since then it's more accurate than what is claimed in the OP) Then by Homogeneity, for each $x \in E$ we get ($\lambda = \frac{c}{\Vert Tx \Vert})$:
$$ \Vert T\big(c\frac{x}{\Vert Tx \Vert}\big) \Vert \leq c \implies \Vert c \frac{x}{\Vert Tx \Vert} \Vert \leq 1 \implies \Vert x \Vert\leq \frac{1}{c} \Vert Tx \Vert$$

Comment: The answer is not good because it didn’t explain what homogeneity is. You can say by homogeneity but you didn’t say what lambda you choose. Yeah

Comment: moreover your first implications is wrong

Comment: Look at the direction of inclusion

Comment: @ZackNi The answer is good. Please make a minimal effort to try to understand the things that people write to try to help you out. Also, searching on google for "homogeneous operator" or "homogeneous function" would have answered your question.

Comment: It should be the norm of x is less than 1/c

Comment: @ZackNi I have finished editing. I realized and fixed the mistake in the original answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand exactly how it works.